# Qiuck tabs shifts the Openlayers map background layer

Tags: 7, google-maps, javascript, blocks

Im displaying the list of locations (address and map Openlayers + Geofield) using views. There is no problems when displaying view in ordinary way, but when the view is displayed inside quicktabs the background shifts about 100px in particular(top-left) direction from the place it should be.

Normal map display

[image]

Same location with shifted map background

[image]

Also, I noticed that after opening Developer tools in Chrome the grey zone without map disappears(fills up with map) and if you click on the map region the red point mark shifts back to the place where it should be.

Any ideas about how to fix this issue ?

Comment: resolved. edit quicktabs.css http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333932/openlayers-inside-jquery-ui-tabs

Answer (score 0):

This is the css/jquery issue .inside a quick tab the map doesn't get load because it is display none initially .when you click on the locations tab it tries to get load but dos not get loaded . you need to play with jquery a little.